# Аналитика для .NET Core сайтов

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, отладка, google-analytics

Как получать информацию о приложении на продакшене? Пока я работаю у себя, я могу поставить брейкпоинты или написать Console.WriteLine("Some message")

Если я пишу мобильное приложение, могу туда интегрировать Yandex.AppMetrica или аналитику гугла, и писать SendEvent("User did something")

Сейчас я делаю сайт на .NET Core + докер. И мне нужно как то узнавать, что внутри него происходит, причем желательно в удобной дашборде. Есть ли какое-нибудь решение наподобии аппметрики или чего то такого, чтобы воткнул в важные методы и смотришь, как продакшен работает.

Comment: Сделайте логи, хотя бы на том же `NLog`.

Comment: Для Asp.Net Core это явно компонент от Microsoft - Azure Application Insights, подробнейшая аналитика проекта в пару кликов. Ну а так, вопрос слишком общий, на него нельзя дать объективный ответ, ибо каждый будет тянуть одеяло на себя, логгеров много, выбирайте сами.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите эту статью. Хорошее стандартное решение для логирования https://www.humankode.com/asp-net-core/logging-with-elasticsearch-kibana-asp-net-core-and-docker